# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at **

Tags: laravel, cors, nuxt.js

So I currently facing this error when try to run my front-end domain

//Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at//

I have an application that is build with nuxt for the frontend and laravel for the backend. how do l add the frontend domain is there a specific file available?, to laravel to allow my frontend access to it's resources.

I'm using the fruitcake laravel, for cors configs, but I'm facing the same error and I even tried adding header configurations in nginx files

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can check in config/cors.php :

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

or try check your nuxt again